# source driver: unknown driver postgres (forgotten import?) even though lib/pq is being imported

Tags: postgresql, go

There are a couple of answers for this up already, but they seemingly tell me to do what I'm already doing, and don't go any deeper into what the issue could be.

A litte recon. I'm trying to get my Go application to run the database migration when it starts up. I have a Postgres database running in a docker container. I can connect to it using my db tools. I can run the migration file from its location using the the command-line. However if I run my service as it stands I get the:

```
source driver: unknown driver postgres (forgotten import?)
```

here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/file"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func init() {
    if err := godotenv.Load(".env"); err != nil {
        log.Println("no .env file found")
    }
}

func main() {
     db_url := os.Getenv("POSTGRES_URL");
     mig_url := os.Getenv("MIGRATION_URL")
    MustMigrateUp(db_url, mig_url)

     _, err := sql.Open("postgres", db_url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func MustMigrateUp(db_url, mig_url string) {
    m, err := migrate.New(
        db_url,
        mig_url,
    )
    println(os.Getenv("POSTGRES_URL"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    if err := m.Up(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

I appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Probably not related to the issue, but what's the use-case for `_, err := sql.Open( ...`, what is it supposed to achieve? Are you aware that this way you're *potentially* leaking connections if you don't close the returned `*sql.DB` instance?

Comment: And given that you're not using the returned `*sql.DB` you may want to skip importing `lib/pq` altogether since that driver ought to already be registered by the `github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres` import.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I wrote that line simply because I can't get the driver to load. I thought maybe trying to open a connection to the database might get it to look for the driver. once I resolve this issue I will be using the connection and will defer a close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

migrate.New() expects the DB url second in the arguments. 
https://godoc.org/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate#New

Don't only code at 3 am kids.

Comment: dang, too accurate. almost 3 am and ran into this.